# Google Earth Engine: ImageCollection.max() recording date of each pixel

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm reducing an image collection to use ImageCollection.max() to create a maximum value composite. Is it possible to know the date for each 'max pixel' chosen in the composite? If so, how would I be able to access it? When I add the layer to my console and inspect each pixel, I just see the value and no properties (where the date would be stored).

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-1-31')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-03-01')


var S2_SR = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
            .filterBounds(geometry)
            .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
            .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',30))

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var imgs = S2_SR.map(addNDVI)
var ndvi_maximg = imgs.select('NDVI').max()
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408420/how-to-extract-periods-in-collections-in-gee

Comment: Thank you! - For those interested I lost the ```system:time_start``` information when initially filtering so had to adjust the code use ```.copyProperties```. 

Then I used ee.Reducer.max() to extract the max of composite and the corresponding band information for that given value.